# How to load only unique and most recent records in SSIS from multiple sources

Tags: ssis

I have two sources- file and DB.

"Product_code" is the key but it can be duplicate since the files can have products modified later than in DB. Both have ModDate field.

I have to load unique and most recent records.

in the DB there are 30 unique IDs and 10 in the file with more recent date, that must replace the rows in the DB with the older date.

What is the most used tool in that type of scenarios?
Any ideas on what will look like the structure in Data Flow be highly appreciated.
Cant use scripts and T-SQL.

I was using this structure

[old ssis structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zFo6.png)

After the suggested use aggregate sort by ID and MAX date

the structure now is like this

[new ssis structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlRlR.png)

but still not getting the result( all columns with the most recent date at the destination DB. Now only one column(ID) at the end.

Thanks

Comment: I recommend loading all of the data into a staging table and using T-SQL to process it. There are ways to do it in SSIS but IMHO they are convoluted

Comment: Thanks but I need some less or more convoluted way in ssis. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use this approach to rank the records. Then you just want to filter on rank = 1 and that should pick out the most recent. https://paultebraak.wordpress.com/2013/02/25/rank-partitioning-in-etl-using-ssis/

Comment: Can this be achieved  with lookups and/ or conditional splits? without this script

Comment: I'm sure it could.

Comment: can't use scripts, can you help with that please?

Comment: Are you saying you aren't allowed to use scripts in SSIS? and you also don't want to use T-SQL? Can you edit your question and include this information and any other constraints?

Comment: sure I'll edit the question, and YES  cant use scripts and T-SQL, only the available tools like lookups, splits, merge joins, unions ect. and logical expressions in them. Thanks

Comment: Scripts are part of the available tools in SSIS. I'll post a suggestion below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the constraints you mention, you can approach it this way:

1. Union both data sources together (you will likely have data type issues)
2. Multicast to path A and path B

Path A:

- Use an aggregate transform to group by Product ID and MAX modifieddate
- The output of this will be two columns: a list of unique products, and their latest modified date

Path B:
Join back to Path A on Product and modified date. The output of this should be the dataset filtered on what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the help, can you take a look at new ssis structure that i'v updated above and tell me if that's what you have in mind. After "Union all" the data with the more recent dates is lost... dont know why?

Comment: The metadata for "Union All.Inputs[Union All Input 2].Columns["Product_Code"]" does not match the metadata for the associated output column. Thats why it gets rejected

Comment: I got pass this changing the data type in connection manager... but still cant get the wright output after the Merge Join. Can you specify what is the right/left join flow to be connected, what type of join to use and how to map/check columns inside Merge Join? Thanks

Comment: We just want to do a filtering activity here so a lookup will probably be fine. Ignore unmatched records.